# Media Viewport Samsung S8 CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix a CSS created by someone else(I took over a job from a other company for my current client)

As for now everything working in my website except on my Samsung Galaxy S8. The footer doesnt follow the rules. I have putted everything I could find online with

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 767px) { 
/* Your Styles... */ 
}
```

But still when I'm going on the website on my S8. The text in a specific part that I want to follow rules..doesnt. (Part is Footer-right2)

On iPad, Desktop its working except this.

Any ideas ?

Here my CSS :

```
@media and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 767px) {      
#footer .footer-wrapper .footer-right2 {
      text-align: center; 
      font-size: 0.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-left: 15px;
   margin:auto;
    max-width:200px;
      }
       #footer .footer-logo {
    display: inline-block;
     padding-left: 15px;
       margin:auto; } }
```

It's working for other size so here one of them as exemple :

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #header .header-wrapper {
    height: 85px; }
  #header .header-toggle-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 7000;
    display: block; }
    #header .header-toggle-menu span {
      display: block;
      width: 42px;
      height: 7px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: #1d1d1d;
      transition: background-color 0.175s linear; }
      #header .header-toggle-menu span + span {
        margin-top: 4px; }
  #header .header-menu {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 6000;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #08ab0f;
    padding-top: 85px;
    transform: translateX(300px);
    transition: transform 0.225s ease-in-out; }
    #header .header-menu a {
      display: block;
      padding: 7px;
      font-size: 0.85em;
      font-weight: 900;
      color: #ffffff;
      transition: none;
      background-color: #e13649;
      margin-bottom: 7px; }
      #header .header-menu a:hover, #header .header-menu a:focus {
        color: #ffffff; }
  #header.active .header-menu {
    transform: translateX(0); }
  #header.active .header-toggle-menu span {
    background-color: #ffffff; }
  #footer .footer-wrapper .form-message {

    top: 85px; }
        #footer .footer-wrapper .footer-right2 {
      text-align: center; 
      font-size: 0.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-left: 15px;
   margin:auto;
    max-width:200px;
      }
       #footer .footer-logo {
    display: inline-block;
     padding-left: 15px;
       margin:auto; }
  #page {
    padding-top: 85px; }
  .slider-container {
    height: 530px;
    background-color: #08ab0f; }
    .slider-container .slider-slides {
      height: 500px; }
      .slider-container .slider-slides .slides-item {
        position: relative; }
        .slider-container .slider-slides .slides-item .item-left, .slider-container .slider-slides .slides-item .item-right {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: auto;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%; }
        .slider-container .slider-slides .slides-item .item-left {
          z-index: 100;
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          text-align: center; }
        .slider-container .slider-slides .slides-item .item-right {
          z-index: 50; }
    .slider-container .slider-navigation {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0; }
  .single-team_member .team-member-header {
    display: block;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap; }
    .single-team_member .team-member-header .header-image {
      padding: 0; }
      .single-team_member .team-member-header .header-image:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: 56.75%; }
    .single-team_member .team-member-header .header-content {
      background-color: #1d1d1d;
      padding: 30px 15px; } }
```

Comment: can you post the footer code?

Comment: Oh.. eh eh it's too long for here

Comment: Here https://github.com/jotunnmedia/Crossfit-514/blob/master/footer.php

Its bit of a mess sorry the guy before me didnt heard about clean file 